# Each Recyclerview item is shown in a whole page

Tags: android, recyclerview-layout

This is my `XML` code for `RecyclerView` item. The problem is, each item is shown in a whole page of app. please help me fixing this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center">


  <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_wall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:riv_corner_radius="5dp" />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/view_wall"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_black_round"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have set your item's width and height to match_parent which makes your item bigger than what you want. use smth like this:

```
      <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:background="@color/black"
android:gravity="center">


<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_wall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:riv_corner_radius="5dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view_wall"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_black_round"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

set `android:layout_height=`  `"wrap_content"` in your `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

See what you are doing basically you are assigning layout_height = `match_parent`  which means your every item will try to take full-screen space instead what you have to do is you can either fix the height of your item by giving static value like

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

another way is to let your view decide how much space it needs by using (recommended way)

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Hope you understand the problem and get possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem has been solved.